# Finding free orbit formula by cartesian coordinate

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, computational-physics, celestial-mechanics

As a simple idea, I want to find a simple orbital function using calculus rather than using the law of Kepler. However, using the recurrence relation is too difficult to solve. Help me to solve...

[image]

Comment: Why do you expect this approach to give a simple formula? It is useful for numeric simulation but not for analytic work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Sandberg, to calculate the orbit is already quite a mess with polar coordinates; with Cartesian is even more difficult (for the Polar, see Goldstein ch.3.7). For numeric calculation, probably Cartesian works well.

To help you try, there are three basic tricks (from the polar solution):

1. all Kepler orbits happens in a plane; thus you can choose the x-y plane, $P_{m2} = (x, y, 0)$ and $V_{m2}= (Vx, Vy, 0)$
2. Start at $t=0$ in some nice place like the aphelion, and orient the axis accordingly:  $P_{m2}(t=0) = (x_0, 0, 0)$, $V_{m2}= (0, Vy_0, 0)$
3. Must impose Conservation of Momentum: $P_{m2} \times V_{m2} = Constant= x_0 * Vy_0$

Now is up to you, patiently write down all equations in the coordinates, you should be able to get a single differential equation for, say $x(t)$. You can either get a diff eq for parametric orbit equation $x(y)$.
You can grind it numerically; analytically, see comments...

Comment: There is no nice analytic solution for $x(t)$ and $y(t)$, or for $r(t)$ and $\theta(t)$.